# Framework7 Svelte routing URL in address bar not working

Tags: html-framework-7

So I've created the standard sample Svelte + Framework7 app using the Framework7-CLI (https://framework7.io/cli/create-app.html). I selected simple web application.

The app is created fine, however, the routing doesn't seem to work if I visit the following URL:

http://localhost:8080/request-and-load/user/123456/

I am able to successfully visit a route if I click on the route link on a page, but the URL remains http://localhost:8080/.  If i try to visit the /request-and-load/user/123456/ url, I just have a blank page with a 404.  Is this URL supposed to work?  Or can I never directly navigate to this route using the URL?

Comment: After some more research, there is pushState option that seems to be able to be assigned somewhere, but I can't find a concrete example.

Answer (score 1):

In App.svelte, I modified the following markup to include pushState, and now it seems to work!

```html
  <!-- Your main view, should have "view-main" class -->
  <View main class="safe-areas" url="/" pushState="true" />
```

Comment: Looks like `pushState` no longer exists, `browserHistory` is a possible alternative.